# database design for optional association and temporal

Tags: database-design, design-pattern, temporal-tables

I'm designing a simple database and I'm stuck with one part. I have a `Task`, `Sweep` and `Spray` entities.

```
       +-------+           
       | Task  |           
       |       |           
       +-+--+--+           
         |  |              
         |  |              
+------+-+  |    +--------+
|Spray |    +----+ Sweep  |
|      |         |        |
+------+         +--------+
```

Each task is done by either a `Sweep` or `Spray` or both. Each `Spray` and `Sweep` has few properties that are only valid for particular `Task` (temporal) and may change over time. For example, spray color is yellow for one task and might be green for another task.

How do I design the tables so that I can query the tasks to see which task was done by which spray and sweep with which properties? Like:

```
task1: spray green  | sweep auto
task2:      -       | sweep manual
task2: spray black  | sweep manual
task2: spray blue   |       -
```

Comment: What values does `Task` hold that are common to both `Spray` and `Sweep`?

Comment: @JohnM, nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If important attributes of Spray or/and Sweep are changing over the time, I'd rather introduce Spray_version and Sweep_version and make them immutable (every change in Spray or Sweep will create a copy in appropriate `*_version` table , so old values are never lost). Thus, you refer to *_version tables.

However, in real world I found it's less expensive (from maintenance and readability perspective) to ignore normalization rules and store extra data in `Tasks`.

Comment: I was thinking the same but I thought there might be better way than de-normalization. But what about being optional? How to avoid storing null if either `Spray` or `Sweep` is not present?